# Match "Nothing" in Notepad++ Regex

Tags: regex, null, notepad++

I want to insert paragraph breaks between sentences in N++. These are my search terms.

```
Search: ([\"|\']*)(\.|\!|\?)([\"|\']*){Space}

Replace: $1$2$3{Space}\n\n
```

I'm assuming that every sentence will end with a period, exclamation mark, or question mark, preceeded and/or succeeded by a single quotemark, a double quotemark, or *nothing at all*, the whole followed by a space.

The above search works, but I really want $1 and $3 to match a single instance of ",' or a null string.

N++ seems to treat \x00 and \0 as control characters rather than "nothing". What am I missing?

EXAMPLES:

Input:

> Testing... Bang! What? "Hello?" Did you say "Hello"? End.

Output:

> Testing...
>
> Bang!
>
> What?
>
> "Hello?"
>
> Did you say "Hello"?
>
> End.

Comment: Please provide some sample text you want to refactor, it's easier to understand your question with a sample. Also looks like you want to swap `*` with `?`, which is `one or zero times`, but it's hard to say without testing.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you don't need to match a preceding quotation mark. Use `$0` to replace the whole text matched. Also, use a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)** to match 1 character, and don't use `|`s inside.

Find what:

```
[.?!]+['"]?[ ]
```

Replace with:

```
$0\n\n
```

- I am using `[ ]` to match a space, so it can be rendered correctly in this post. Use it as it is, or simply put a <kbd>space</kbd>, either way will work.